# Bootstrap label and input sizing in a form group

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have an asp page using bootstrap and I can't figure out how to change the size of a label in a form group. If I change the `<div>` column size it changes the width for the label and input. I need the label to be long but the input to be short. Here is what I have. Pretty basic. In the code below i just need the label to be size 8 and the input size 3. I've tried wrapping the input in its own div but the formatting looks really bad.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-xs-8">
      <asp:label class="control-label dark-label">Inititiating Date: (if different than request date)</asp:label>
      <asp:TextBox ID="initDate" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Inititiating Date"></asp:TextBox>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can add the label and the input grid classes (`col-xs-`)

**Like this:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label dark-label col-xs-8">Inititiating Date: (if different than request date)</label>
  <input class="col-xs-3" type="text" ID="initDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Inititiating Date" />
</div>
```